# Insert a script in Head of the application

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using NextJs and i want to add google analytics in my application.

```html
<Head>
     <title>My app</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
     <meta name="keywords" content="test" />
     <meta charSet="utf-8" />
     <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
 </Head>
```

When i hover over the script `]||[];w[l].push({`, i get:
[image]

Because of this issue i can't run the app. Why it happens and how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it like this:

```
<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `
(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');
` }} async />
```

Comment: but why we have to add this `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `?

Comment: JSX expect a single JS expression so you cannot add directly the Tag Manager snippet, and when directly inserting js or html into a tag, React force you to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML to remind you that it is risky. Another solution would bet to extract the snippet into its own function and call it; but by doing this I had issue with GTM and I went back to this solution.

Comment: could you take a look please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65000491/run-a-script-depending-by-environment-in-nextjs

Comment: could you help?